# How do I remove webforms from content types?

Tags: forms, nodes

Currently, our site is built so that anytime a specific type of new content is created, the page automatically includes a form required for the end user.  Due to tracking issues we're having with other software, we would like to remove these automatic forms from this specific resource type so that the resource is no longer gated.

Can anyone explain how I can make this change to my current content type so that we're not forced to create a whole new content type and replacing things systematically?

Comment: Do you have any custom modules installed? With custom I mean, that they are not hosted on drupal.org. Anyhow, it would be necessary for us to understand the origin of your forms, so maybe you can make a list of all your enabled modules and post it into a pastebin?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) module (I'm not 100% sure from your question), and you want to disable the webform functionality for the content type, then you can do this on the settings page of the content type (Admin > Structure > Content types). There should be a a fieldset or vertical tab called "Webform", and when you click on that there should be a checkbox that you can disable.

[image]

But be aware that this removes the form from all previously created nodes too, not only for the new ones.

If you're not using webform then please specify what modules do you use so that we can understand how this functionality is build into your site.

Comment: Thanks for response berliner.  I don't really have a background in any of this, so I'm sure I'm not using the correct terminology.

Apparently we don't have the same set-up (modules?).  When I view the content type, there is no fieldset called "Webform" - just the following:


![enter image description here][1]

 


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hpPfn.png

In this case, would I need to check elsewhere to disable the forms?

Comment: @user26108 Can you post a screenshot of the form that you want to remove? Add it to your question. Try to make your question better understandable. As I said before, I just guessed that you are using the webforms module, but apparently you don't ;)